# Integral over tetrahedron

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $S$ be the getrahedron in $\mathbb{R^3}$ having vertices $(0,0,0),(1,2,3),(0,1,2),(-1,1,1)$. Evaluate $\int_{S}f$ where $f(x,y,z) = x+2y-z$. You may use a suitable linear transformation as a coordinate change

---

How do I solve this? As I've never studied mathematics before jumping into duplicate degree, I have very weak background on mathematics. Anybody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Find a linear transformation which maps the tetrahedron to something which is easier to parameterize (I'd try taking the three non zero vectors to (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1)).
After you figure out the parametrization, you can use it to evaluate the integral using standard variable substitution.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? How do I find it?

Comment: Are you familiar with matrix multiplication?  A suitable transformation is $$ \pmatrix{u_1\\u_2\\u_3} =T(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \pmatrix{1&0&-1\\2&1&1\\3&2&1}^{-1} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's the structure of the calculation

Step 1: find a linear map which maps the tetrahedron to something easy to parametrize.

Clearly a linear map can only take 0 to 0, so we can only play with the three other vectors.

We use the linear map defined by $(1,2,3)\mapsto(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,2)\mapsto(0,1,0)$ and $(-1,1,1)\mapsto(0,0,1)$.
Since these three vectors are independent (why?) this is a well defined linear mapping.

Moreover, since we map to a standard base we know that its inverse will be given by the matrix  $\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & -1\\
2 & 1 & 1\\
3 & 2 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$.

We denote this map $T$.

(If you are unsure about something we did so far you should revise linear algebra).

Step 2: Find a parametrization

Geomerically, the new tetrahedron is much easier to picture.

I'll leave the details to you, but it is parametrized by $\{(x,y,z) | 0\le x\le 1, 0\le y \le 1-x, 0\le z \le 1-(x+y)\}$

Note that the boundaries on $z$ are a function of $x,y$ and the boundaries on $y$ is a function of $x$ which will be useful for integration.

Step 3: use variable substitution.

Let $V$ denote the tetrahedron, then

$$\int_V f dv = \int_{T(V)} f\circ T |DT| dv$$

Note that $DT$ is simply the matrix representing $T$ (why?) which is the inverse of the matrix from before.

I'll leave you again with the details of calculating the matrix and its determinant, but denote for now $|DT|=a$. I also leave to you to calculate $T\circ f$, which we will denote for now as $g$.

Putting everything in place we get that

$$\int_{T(V)} f\circ T |DT| dv = a\int_{T(V)} g dv$$

and using the parametrization from before

$$\int_{T(V)} g dv = \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} \int_0^{1-x-y} g(x,y,z) dzdydx$$

which should turn out an elementary calculation